# Differences in QGIS expression functions using Geometry generator vs. Geometry by expression

Tags: qgis, expression, geometry-generator

### Create a line to the closest neighbor: Geometry generator

Using QGIS, I have a point layer and use the following expression with Geometry generator to create a line, connecting each point to its closest neighbor:

```
make_line (
    $geometry, 
    overlay_nearest('pt',$geometry)[0])
```

### Create a line to the closest neighbor: Geometry by expression

When I use the same expression with Geometry by expression, however, I don't get any output. I have to change the expression in the following way to get the same result:

```
make_line (
    $geometry, 
    overlay_nearest('pt',$geometry,limit:=2)[1])
```

### Difference between both methods

So  with geometry by expression, overlay_nearest seems to get the current feature as the (1st) nearest feature, whereas in Geometry generator, the 1st, nearest geometry is the closest one that is not identical with the current feature.

### Question

Why does it work differently using Geometry generator and Geometry by expression? I know that Geometry generator is for visualization only, whereas Geoemtry by expression creates real geometries. This, however, does not explain the difference, as far as I can see.

### Example

*Each point connected by a line to its closest neighbor:*
[image]

Comment: Good question, but only a QGIS developer like Nyall Dawson or others can answer here, so I would suggest asking the QGIS-developer listed question : https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer